# How to fix the following error when trying to load a model "KeyError: 'CaseFoldUTF8' while loading the model"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

Observing `KeyError:'CaseFoldUTF8' while loading the model` when loading the model that I had fine-tuned using pre trained BERT from tf-hub

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I got the same error. Adding `import tensorflow_text` at the top worked for me.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I was pulling my hair out for a good hour trying to figure out why my script had been working in a notebook for a whole day, then suddenly it started throwing that error. Turns out all I had done was remove the unused import mentioned in your post. What a weird setup. Cheers!